# SpecialKey foreground color w/ cursorline set

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, whitespace, cursorline

In [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869057/vim-linenr-and-cursorline-colour-configuration-change), it's observed that there is a highlight group for `CursorLineNr`, which applies to the line number for the cursor line when `set cursorline` is on.

I notice that using cursorline also changes the color for another highlight group, `SpecialKey`, which applies if you have, e.g.:

```
 set list listchars=tab:\|_,trail:-
```

The problem with this for me is I use a dark background (and so a dark cursorline).  My normal `SpecialKey` setting is also very dark, so that the `listchar` symbols are only marginally visible.  But using `cursorline` *they're white*, which makes the `trail` char indistinguishable from having actually hit `-`.  The trail character is used every time you type a space at the end of a line, so this is more than a minor issue; usually typing a line from beginning to end involves a number of spaces that should be easily distinguished from a dash typo while working (or vice versa, a space typo when you intended a dash).

Since none of the other highlight groups seem to be affected, something like `CursorLineNr` is presumably being applied, but looking through the `hi` list I don't see anything appropriate.

Does anyone know what this is?  Better yet, does anyone know of a way to modify any highlight group for cursorline?

Comment: I only [highlight the cursor line briefly](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/b7c7df4fa395d53b6908ed6dbec9a3ea3d1a204b/.vim/plugin/highlight_line_after_jump.vim) after I have jumped 2 or more lines. When I am editing text, the cursorline is off. If you can get used to that behaviour, it could mitigate your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been struggling with that behavior for a *long* time.

Basically, the foreground color of `SpecialKey` on the current line is changed to the foreground color of `Normal` if:

- the `cursorline` option is enabled,
- the `CursorLine` highlight group has a background color set.

I've never been able to fix that behavior, no matter what I tried. The problem lies somewhere in Vim's source code.

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted!  I've changed my trail char to `~` which is a little less confusing (might also look for some obscure unicode char to use).

Comment: I saw this behavior even without a background color for the CursorLine group. I tried to disable it (i.e. `none`), tried to leave its default value (it was underlined), the spaces still changed their foreground color

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was the following lines in my `.vimrc` (based on [Igor Mikushkin's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13213/22062)).

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call matchadd('SpecialKey', '\s\+')
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call matchadd('NonText', '\n\+')
```

`VimEnter` only works for the first file you open, not for files/tabs you open afterwards. `BufNewFile,BufRead` has worked so far for all the buffers I've opened.

The first line covers whitespace characters. Vim highlights them in the `SpecialKey` group, so we apply those styles to them.

The second line covers newlines. Vim highlights them in the `NonText` group, so we apply those styles to them. You only really need the second line if your `NonText` characters are highlighted differently than `SpecialKey` characters.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following lines in .vimrc fixed the problem for me.

```
au VimEnter * call matchadd('SpecialKey', '^\s\+', -1)
au VimEnter * call matchadd('SpecialKey', '\s\+$', -1)
```

It overrides other styles application for tabs and trailing spaces inside a cursor line.

Comment: why are you storing the `matchadd()` result in a variable, if you don't use it?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you, it is fixed now.

Comment: This works for me too using NeoVim.

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another "solution", actually sort of a kludge for this problem.

I have custom syntax groups for such thing as "listchars".

Like this:

```
hi WhiteSpaceChar ctermfg=251 guifg=#999999
call matchadd("WhiteSpaceChar", "[ \t]")
```

You could do something like this (though I didn't test it):

```
hi TrailChar ctermfg=251 guifg=#999999
" the \v in the regex is Vim's flag to use Perl-like regex syntax
call matchadd("TrailChar", "\v +$")
```

But there are at least two problems with this approach:

1. when you split a window, or create a new tab etc. the highlight becomes broken in the current window, like this:

[image: white space highlight becomes broken, when a new window opens]

To fix this I have special functions like:

```
fun! ResetHiglightJS()
  set syntax=javascript
  "these are for the IndentLine plugin
  "IndentLinesDisable
  "IndentLinesEnable
endfun
```

for each syntax group, which I use often, to fix the highlighting manually. You can do this in other way like autocommands or manually setting the value for the syntax option. To make the syntax resetting work one also must have this:

```
call matchadd("WhiteSpaceChar", "[ \t]")
```

in each corresponding syntax file, like `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim`

2. This approach does not work normally with at least one plugin — the IndentLine one, so I was forced to stick to an old version of it by setting manually `let g:indentLine_newVersion = 0`, where the plugin worked normally.

But in other way this approach works normally without the IndentLine plugin:

[image: white spaces have a desired color in the cursor line]

And acceptable with it:

[image: indentLine color in the cursor line]